# Android Realm migrating from 1.x to 2.x

Tags: android, database, realm, realm-migration

We're trying to migrate Realm from 1.x to a 2.x version. Do we need to provide migration in this case? We would like to keep the data obviously, but I think Realm deletes it if you update the app now. We havent released the 2.x version yet so now we need to deal with migration.

Comment: Realm triggers migration if you add field, remove field, add class, remove class, add index, remove index, add primary key, remove primary key, and so on.

Comment: https://blog.realm.io/realm-java-2-0-mobile-platform-support/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Realm should be migrated automatically to the new format going from 1.x to 2.x since the file format changed.

https://blog.realm.io/realm-java-2-0-mobile-platform-support/

Answer (score 0):

What behavior have you experienced when upgrading from 1.x to 2.x on a test device?

If you have `deletedRealmIfMigrationNeeded()` set on your `RealmConfiguration` then it will delete the data. You will need remove that line from your `RealmConfiguration` and add a `migration(YourMigration.class)`

I would recommend a lot of testing for this changing, and ensure you add all past database changes the migration.

See here for information on how to do a migration: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations

Comment: Well the question in general was more about if we need migration in this instance. The documentation says that we need migration if our schema changes but in this case it does not, we only upgraded the realm version in our gradle file.